# Indexes of different words not matching the numbers list

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a program that takes a list of words(text) and adds numbers to the numbers lists(called numbers) to represent the indexes of the original text e.g. the phrase "the sailor went to sea sea sea to see what he could see see see but all that he could see see see was the bottom of the deep blue sea sea sea" should be returned as "1 2 3 4 5 5 5 4 6 7 8 9 6 6 6 10 11 12 8 9 6 6 6 13 1 14 15 16 17 5 5 5" however is returned as "1 2 3 4 5 5 5 4 9 10 11 12 9 9 9 13 14 15 11 12 9 9 9 16 1 17 18 1 19 20 5 5 5", causing a problem.

This is the part of the program that is the problem:

```
for position, item in enumerate(text):
    if text.count(item) < 2:
        numbers.append(max(numbers) + 1)
    else:
        numbers.append(text.index(item) + 1)
```

The "numbers" and "text" are both lists.

Is there a way to modify this code slightly so that the numbers still remain in the normal order with them being in separate lists without having to start this part from scratch?

Comment: Please do not ask the *exact same question* you already asked (and got answers to).

Comment: It`s not the exact same as I'm asking for a modification for this code rather than a replacement for it